# Calculate longitude/latitude for geographic centroid

Tags: r, spatial, centroid

I want to do some spatial statistic analysis with the county-level crop yield data in Nebraska for the STAT class. For that I need the longitude and latitude of the geographic centroids of each county. Anybody know how to do it in R? I know it can be done in ArcGIS but I have no access to it now.

Comment: This question should be moved to http://gis.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't give any details where you got your shapefile from, but I got one from [here](http://www.dnr.ne.gov/boundaries-plss) and you can use `gCentroid` from `rgeos` thusly:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

nebraska <- readOGR("CountyBoundsUTM/", "CountyUTM")

gCentroid(nebraska, byid=TRUE)

## SpatialPoints:
##           x       y
## 0  721768.5 4636738
## 1  430938.8 4524651
## 2  698036.4 4566570
## 3  370970.6 4641340
## ...
## 89 623301.6 4603228
## 90 618883.0 4486931
## 91 439295.3 4582756
## 92 493680.8 4522680
## Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=NAD83
## +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Comment: Hi @hrbrmstr. I've tried your solution to get the result as a `data.frame` but then I loose the `id` information. Like this `df <-as.data.frame(gCentroid(gridriopoly500, byid=TRUE))` . Is it possible to keep the id info?

Comment: You might want to post that as a separate question. There's a way to do it (easily) but I'd rather not try to find that `CountyUTM` file to show it (and the OP here didn't need it, apparently).

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr. I've just posted a new question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571956/get-data-frame-with-polygons-id-and-centroid-lat-long-information-from-shapefi)

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract centroids of `SpatialPolygons*` objects with `coordinates`, though the centroids won't be returned as `SpatialPoints` as with `rgeos::gCentroid`.

For example:

```
library(rgdal)
download.file('http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/pub/data/nationalatlas/countyp020_nt00009.tar.gz', 
              f <- tempfile()) # ~ 4.5 Mb
untar(f, exdir=tempdir())
counties <- readOGR(tempdir(), 'countyp020')
xy <- coordinates(counties)
head(xy)

#        [,1]     [,2]
# 0 -153.3905 69.30193
# 1 -156.0582 71.33094
# 2 -155.6695 71.24763
# 3 -155.5164 71.23148
# 4 -155.1846 71.18189
# 5 -155.6126 71.00725
```

Note that, as pointed out by @Spacedman in the comments, the polygons should be projected to a planar coordinate system first.

Comment: Those coordinates are computed using lat-long as planar geometry which is not the right way to go about it. Convert to a planar CRS, get centroids, turn into SpatialPoints, convert back to Lat-long. In this case the difference is pretty small but its something you should know about.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of the [*sf* package](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/index.html) (I think since version 1) use the [S2 library](https://s2geometry.io/) from Google for spherical geometry calculations. The advantage is that centroid calculations are not simply planar. The relevant method is `st_centroid()`. An example for a region with a significant spatial extent:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
# ne_countries() returns 'sp'-type data by default
nc <- ne_countries(continent = "Asia", returnclass = "sf")
  
library(sf)
# long-lat data in WGS84
st_crs(nc)
# use st_geometry() to plot only the polygons and not the associated data
plot(st_geometry(nc), axes = T)
plot(st_centroid(st_geometry(nc)), pch = "+", col = "red", add = T)

# 'sf' integrates nicely with 'ggplot2':
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(nc) + geom_sf() +
    geom_sf(aes(geometry = st_centroid(st_geometry(nc))), colour = "red")
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `get_map()` function from the `ggplot2` package to extract the US county map data from the `maps` package to a dataframe. Then you can calculate the mid points of the ranges of the lat/lon columns by county (or whatever method you want to use to define geographic center).

Comment: mean of lat/lon ranges are only a rough close approximation to the centroid of the polygons.